# Does this code exploit Java compiler generics verification limitations

Tags: java, generics, javac

While refactoring code I stumbled upon strange Java compiler (Oracle 1.8.0_101) behavior. My assumption is, if I replace all occurrences of `List<T>` by `T` (without using any methods from `List`) the code should compile, if it compiled before the change.

Now have a look at this code:

```
interface Mapper<T, U extends MapperProvider<U>> extends Function<T, List<U>> {}

interface MapperProvider<V> {
    Mapper<V, ?> provide();
}

private <V extends MapperProvider<V>> void use(V c) {
    use2(c.provide().apply(c));
}

private <W extends MapperProvider<W>> void use2(List<W> c) {
}
```

This code [compiles](http://ideone.com/sL2T3q). When I replace `List<U>` by `U` and `List<W>` by `W`:

```
interface Mapper<T, U extends MapperProvider<U>> extends Function<T, U> {}

interface MapperProvider<V> {
    Mapper<V, ?> provide();
}

private <V extends MapperProvider<V>> void use(V c) {
    use2(c.provide().apply(c));
}

private <W extends MapperProvider<W>> void use2(W c) {
}
```

it [does not compile](http://ideone.com/tYUQZ2) any more:

```
Error:(201, 17) java: method use2 in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
  required: W
  found: capture#1 of ?
  reason: inference variable W has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: capture#1 of ?
    lower bounds: MapperProvider<capture#1 of ?>
```

which is correct from my point of view. `use2` should be declared to receive `MapperProvider<?>`.

Why does the Java compiler treat the first version as legal?

Comment: The code you have provided does not compile. Definition of the Function interface is missing.

Comment: Andriy, I used only classes available in JRE. I skipped the import statements for clarity. Follow the links if you want to copy 100% complete code.

Comment: Interestingly, for me the code shows no errors in Intellij but fails a command line compile using the same JDK.

Comment: The same is true for eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Oracle thinks that this is a bug. I opened a bug report and Oracle confirmed: [JDK-8172222](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172222)